# Toolbar в AppBarLayout накладывается на содержимое вместо смещения контента

Tags: android, android-fragment, toolbar, android-constraintlayout

Есть 2 фрагмента, один из них имеет родительский контейнер AppBarLayout с Toolbar внутри, другой - Constraint Layout. Мне нужно, чтобы после добавления второго фрагмента учитывалось динамическое изменение размера первого фрагмента (с AppBarLayout) и происходило смещение, если размер первого увеличивается (список). Но по итогу один фрагмент перекрывает второй или наоборот, в зависимости от значения параметра app:layout_behavior у AppBarLayout. Не нашёл значения для параметра, когда вместо накладывания происходит смещение. Возможно, ранее уже так делал, но не вспомню, как именно. Спасибо!

Содержимое первого фрагмента:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/create_route"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dividerSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ECECEC"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/infoList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/infoList"/>
```

Содержимое второго фрагмента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
 ....
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Оба в контейнере

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: Думаю, имеет смысл показать разметку для начала)

Comment: Дополнил разметкой первое сообщение